# Form handling without Controller, react-hook-form

Tags: react-hook-form

I have been working on form using the react-hook-form for quite a long, I have used v6 and v7 of the library.

While handling form for material-ui, react-hook-form docs states that we should use Controller Component, [link](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries) for the doc.
When using the Controller we have to write a lot of code which I personally don't like, so I have been using a different approach to handle form using watch,  without using Controller Component.

Till now I have not faced any issues using this approach and I have to write less code as well.

I just wanted to know the drawbacks of this approach, as I don't want to change my code in future because of performance issues.

```
import { Button, Container, FormLabel, Grid, MenuItem, Select } from '@mui/material'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

export default function Home() {

  const countries = [
    { id: 1, name: 'India' },
    { id: 2, name: 'USA' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Canada' }
  ]

  const { register, handleSubmit, control, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      country: 'India'
    }
  })

  const watchFields = watch()

  const submit = (data) => {
    console.log({ data })
  }

  return (
    <Container sx={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <FormLabel>Please select your country</FormLabel>
          <Select
            fullWidth
            defaultValue={'India'}
            value={watchFields.country}
            label="Country"
            {...register('country')}
          >
            {countries.map(country => <MenuItem key={country.id} value={country.name}>{country.name}</MenuItem>)}
          </Select>
        </Grid>
        <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use `useController` instead of `<Controller />`?

Comment: For each different type of input element I have make seperate useController. I want to know - does using watch() can cause any performance issues.